# Odoo 10 - QWeb PDF sale order report, how to access company_registry field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I am trying to include `company_registry` field content in the sale order to show the company registry of our company.

I have tried:

```
<span t-field="doc.company.company_registry"/>
```

Without success.
What shall I do to retrieve that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with **company_id**, something like this:

```
<span t-field="doc.company_id.company_registry"/>
```

'couse the definition for company field in 'sale.order' model is:

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company', default=lambda self: self.env['res.company']._company_default_get('sale.order'))
```

Take a look the source code in this [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/0351677a00df8bd76fa207a38dc2ecdefdc6940a/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L155)

I hope this answer can be helful for you.